# How to check if a thread is currently running

Tags: multithreading, delphi, threadpool, delphi-2007

I am designing a thread pool with following features.

- New thread should be spawned only when all other threads are running.
- Maximum number of thread should be configurable.
- When a thread is waiting, it should be able to handle new requests.
- Each IO operation should call a callback on completion
- Thread should have a way to manage request its serving and IO callbacks

Here is the code:

```
unit ThreadUtilities;

interface
uses
Windows, SysUtils, Classes;

type
    EThreadStackFinalized = class(Exception);
    TSimpleThread = class;

    // Thread Safe Pointer Queue
    TThreadQueue = class
    private
        FFinalized: Boolean;
        FIOQueue: THandle;
    public
        constructor Create;
        destructor Destroy; override;
        procedure Finalize;
        procedure Push(Data: Pointer);
        function Pop(var Data: Pointer): Boolean;
        property Finalized: Boolean read FFinalized;
    end;

    TThreadExecuteEvent = procedure (Thread: TThread) of object;

    TSimpleThread = class(TThread)
    private
        FExecuteEvent: TThreadExecuteEvent;
    protected
        procedure Execute(); override;
    public
        constructor Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean; ExecuteEvent: TThreadExecuteEvent; AFreeOnTerminate: Boolean);
    end;

    TThreadPoolEvent = procedure (Data: Pointer; AThread: TThread) of Object;

    TThreadPool = class(TObject)
    private
        FThreads: TList;
        fis32MaxThreadCount : Integer;
        FThreadQueue: TThreadQueue;
        FHandlePoolEvent: TThreadPoolEvent;
        procedure DoHandleThreadExecute(Thread: TThread);
        procedure SetMaxThreadCount(const pis32MaxThreadCount : Integer);
        function GetMaxThreadCount : Integer;

    public
        constructor Create( HandlePoolEvent: TThreadPoolEvent; MaxThreads: Integer = 1); virtual;
        destructor Destroy; override;
        procedure Add(const Data: Pointer);
        property MaxThreadCount : Integer read GetMaxThreadCount write SetMaxThreadCount;
    end;


implementation



constructor      TThreadQueue.Create;
begin         
    //-- Create IO Completion Queue
    FIOQueue := CreateIOCompletionPort(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, 0, 0, 0);
    FFinalized := False;
end;

destructor TThreadQueue.Destroy;
begin
    //-- Destroy Completion Queue
    if (FIOQueue = 0) then
        CloseHandle(FIOQueue);
    inherited;
end;

procedure TThreadQueue.Finalize;
begin
    //-- Post a finialize pointer on to the queue
    PostQueuedCompletionStatus(FIOQueue, 0, 0, Pointer($FFFFFFFF));
    FFinalized := True;
end;


function TThreadQueue.Pop(var Data: Pointer): Boolean;
var
    A: Cardinal;
    OL: POverLapped;
begin
    Result := True;
    if (not FFinalized) then 
        //-- Remove/Pop the first pointer from the queue or wait
        GetQueuedCompletionStatus(FIOQueue, A, Cardinal(Data), OL, INFINITE);

    //-- Check if we have finalized the queue for completion
    if FFinalized or (OL = Pointer($FFFFFFFF)) then begin
        Data := nil;
        Result := False;
        Finalize;
    end;
end;

procedure TThreadQueue.Push(Data: Pointer);
begin        
    if FFinalized then
        Raise EThreadStackFinalized.Create('Stack is finalized');
    //-- Add/Push a pointer on to the end of the queue
    PostQueuedCompletionStatus(FIOQueue, 0, Cardinal(Data), nil);
end;

{ TSimpleThread }

constructor TSimpleThread.Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean;
  ExecuteEvent: TThreadExecuteEvent; AFreeOnTerminate: Boolean);
begin
    FreeOnTerminate := AFreeOnTerminate;
    FExecuteEvent := ExecuteEvent;
    inherited Create(CreateSuspended);
end;
```

Changed the code as suggested by J... also added critical sections but the problem i am facing now is that when i am trying call multiple task only one thread is being used, Lets say if i added 5 threads in the pool then only one thread is being used which is thread 1. Please check my client code as well in the below section.

```
procedure TSimpleThread.Execute;
begin
    //    if Assigned(FExecuteEvent) then
//        FExecuteEvent(Self);
    while not self.Terminated do begin
    try
//      FGoEvent.WaitFor(INFINITE);
//      FGoEvent.ResetEvent;
      EnterCriticalSection(csCriticalSection);
      if self.Terminated then break;


      if Assigned(FExecuteEvent) then
        FExecuteEvent(Self);
    finally
      LeaveCriticalSection(csCriticalSection);
//      HandleException;
    end;
end;
end;
```

In the `Add` method, how can I check if there is any thread which is not busy, if it is not busy then reuse it else create a new thread and add it in ThreadPool list?

```
{ TThreadPool }
procedure TThreadPool.Add(const Data: Pointer);
begin
  FThreadQueue.Push(Data);
//  if FThreads.Count < MaxThreadCount then
//  begin
//    FThreads.Add(TSimpleThread.Create(False, DoHandleThreadExecute, False));
//  end;
end;

constructor TThreadPool.Create(HandlePoolEvent: TThreadPoolEvent;
  MaxThreads: Integer);
begin
    FHandlePoolEvent := HandlePoolEvent;
    FThreadQueue := TThreadQueue.Create;
    FThreads := TList.Create;
    FThreads.Add(TSimpleThread.Create(False, DoHandleThreadExecute, False));
end;

destructor TThreadPool.Destroy;
var
    t: Integer;
begin
    FThreadQueue.Finalize;
    for t := 0 to FThreads.Count-1 do
        TThread(FThreads[t]).Terminate;
    while (FThreads.Count =  0) do begin
        TThread(FThreads[0]).WaitFor;
        TThread(FThreads[0]).Free;
        FThreads.Delete(0);
    end;
    FThreadQueue.Free;
    FThreads.Free;
    inherited;
end;

procedure TThreadPool.DoHandleThreadExecute(Thread: TThread);
var
    Data: Pointer;
begin
    while FThreadQueue.Pop(Data) and (not TSimpleThread(Thread).Terminated) do begin
        try
            FHandlePoolEvent(Data, Thread);
        except
        end;
    end;
end;

function TThreadPool.GetMaxThreadCount: Integer;
begin
  Result := fis32MaxThreadCount;
end;

procedure TThreadPool.SetMaxThreadCount(const pis32MaxThreadCount: Integer);
begin
  fis32MaxThreadCount := pis32MaxThreadCount;
end;

end.
```

Client Code :
This the client i created to log the data in text file :
unit ThreadClient;

```
interface

uses Windows, SysUtils, Classes, ThreadUtilities;

type
    PLogRequest = ^TLogRequest;
    TLogRequest = record
        LogText: String;
    end;

    TThreadFileLog = class(TObject)
    private
        FFileName: String;
        FThreadPool: TThreadPool;
        procedure HandleLogRequest(Data: Pointer; AThread: TThread);
    public
        constructor Create(const FileName: string);
        destructor Destroy; override;
        procedure Log(const LogText: string);
        procedure SetMaxThreadCount(const pis32MaxThreadCnt : Integer);
    end;

implementation

(* Simple reuse of a logtofile function for example *)
procedure LogToFile(const FileName, LogString: String);
var
    F: TextFile;
begin
    AssignFile(F, FileName);
    if not FileExists(FileName) then
        Rewrite(F)
    else
        Append(F);
    try
        Writeln(F, DateTimeToStr(Now) + ': ' + LogString);
    finally
        CloseFile(F);
    end;
end;

constructor TThreadFileLog.Create(const FileName: string);
begin
    FFileName := FileName;
    //-- Pool of one thread to handle queue of logs
    FThreadPool := TThreadPool.Create(HandleLogRequest, 5);
end;

destructor TThreadFileLog.Destroy;
begin
    FThreadPool.Free;
    inherited;
end;

procedure TThreadFileLog.HandleLogRequest(Data: Pointer; AThread: TThread);
var
    Request: PLogRequest;
    los32Idx : Integer;
begin
  Request := Data;
  try
    for los32Idx := 0 to 100 do
    begin
      LogToFile(FFileName, IntToStr( AThread.ThreadID) + Request^.LogText);
    end;
  finally
    Dispose(Request);
  end;
end;

procedure TThreadFileLog.Log(const LogText: string);
var
    Request: PLogRequest;
begin
    New(Request);
    Request^.LogText := LogText;
    FThreadPool.Add(Request);
end;
procedure TThreadFileLog.SetMaxThreadCount(const pis32MaxThreadCnt: Integer);
begin
  FThreadPool.MaxThreadCount := pis32MaxThreadCnt;
end;

end.
```

This is the form application where i added three buttons, each button click will write some value to the file with thread id and text msg. But the problem is thread id is always same

```
unit ThreadPool;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ThreadClient;

type
  TForm5 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Button3: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    fiFileLog : TThreadFileLog;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form5: TForm5;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm5.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fiFileLog.Log('Button one click');
end;

procedure TForm5.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fiFileLog.Log('Button two click');
end;

procedure TForm5.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fiFileLog.Log('Button three click');
end;

procedure TForm5.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fiFileLog.SetMaxThreadCount(StrToInt(Edit1.Text));
end;

procedure TForm5.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fiFileLog := TThreadFileLog.Create('C:/test123.txt');
end;

end.
```

Comment: This isn't a suitable question for Stack Overflow. Please read the topics in the [help].

Comment: Where should i ask then?? This is a technical question, i am trying to design threadpool in D2007 but facing some problem in spawning of new thread when the request arrives to the threadpool. If you can reffer some guidelines then that would be really helpful. Thanks

Comment: "facing some problem in spawning of new thread ".  Then you could show the code involved in that and describe how the problem manifests itself, and where.

Comment: Did you read the topics in the [help] yet? They will explain what type of questions are consider on topic here.

Comment: "You need to design a thread pool with following features" You want us to do your work for you? How much are we getting paid?

Comment: Sorry, i am new here. And its not about working for me, i am just asking a guidelines that's all.

Comment: @MartynA  I have added the code.

Comment: @NandlalKumar Ok, that's step 1.  Step 2 is now to make a question - what is wrong with your code? Which part of it do you require help with?  What isn't working?  Be specific - if there are ten things, then break the problem into smaller parts and ask ten separate, specific questions.

Comment: thanks @J... for the guideline.

Comment: The question is still not a good one. I cannot understand the reopen votes.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The question is not outstanding, but at least now it is reasonably scoped and answerable.

Comment: @J... Not in my opinion it is not. There's no question at all. Anywhere. There's a huge list of requirements, and some code. No commentary on the code. Not even close to a specific question. Reopening questions like this just teaches new askers that they don't need to ask questions that fit.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `[how do I] check if there is any thread which is not busy, if it is not busy then reuse it else create a new thread and add it in ThreadPool list`.  I think that's reasonably specific.

Comment: @J... If that's the question, how does your answer relate to it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The first problem OP needs to tackle on the road to an answer to the question above is the `if it is not busy then reuse it` part.  I thought I would start there specifically and then offer some general advice for the following steps.  Like I said, the question can stand some improvement.  It would probably be better phrased as a `How can I re-use a thread` type of wording - feel free to do that if you wish. As it stands, I don't consider it bad enough that it can't be helpfully answered - there's enough focus in the question now to see where OP is at and what the next step is.

Comment: @NandlalKumar I see you've updated your question with more questions.  If the answer to this question has helped you move forward and you now find you have new questions then the best suggestion is to post those as new, separate questions here.

Comment: @J... I added client application where i am trying log some message using three buttons one by one. To keep a thread busy, i added in a loop of 100 iterations. But i think i may got the problem, since i am writing to a particular file which i am locking at the time of execute by using critical section. So even though when i try to press buttons multiple times, the request gets added in a queue and when thread gets free the same thread starts executing the other request from the queue.

Comment: But if i remove the critical section then whenever i press multiple buttons at the same time, the same thread takes over it and start executing the other request immediately. 
Here i need some help so that when my first thread is busy in writing the file then second thread should start looking into the queue for the request.
May be my client example can be improved or am i missing something in main thread code.???

Comment: @NandlalKumar I'll say again - this belongs in a new question.  Stack Overflow has a very strict format - one question, one answer.  If you have several questions, or new questions, you need to post them separately.  Now that you have modified your original question the answer below makes less sense.  Continuing to change your original question or append new questions is *not* acceptable.

Comment: Ok @J... i will post another question. But need to wait another 5 days to ask another question because few people voted negative point for this question which restricted me to ask another question. :(

Comment: @NandlalKumar  This is a bit surprising - the behaviour is deliberate (see : http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271542/327083) but in this case it may be that the algorithm is not taking into account that the question was subsequently edited and improved.  It does take into account your average question score, however, and your previous question remains at -6, unfortunately.  Easiest just to wait it out - it seems like you are learning and putting in the effort to ask better questions so I would not get discouraged!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, and probably most strongly advisable, you might consider using a library like [OmniThread](http://otl.17slon.com/) to implement a threadpool.  The hard work is done for you and you will likely end up making a substandard and buggy product with a roll-your-own solution.  Unless you have special requirements this is probably the fastest and easiest solution.

That said, if you want to try to do this...

What you might consider is to just make all of the threads in your pool at startup rather than on-demand.  If the server is going to busy at any point then it will eventually end up with a pool of `MaxThreadCount` soon enough anyway.

In any case, if you want to keep a pool of threads alive and available for work then they would need to follow a slightly different model than what you have written.

Consider:

```
procedure TSimpleThread.Execute;
begin
    if Assigned(FExecuteEvent) then
        FExecuteEvent(Self);
end;
```

Here when you run your thread it will execute this callback and then terminate.  This doesn't seem to be what you want.  What you seem to want is to keep the thread alive but waiting for its next work package.  I use a base thread class (for pools) with an execute method that looks something like this (this is somewhat simplified):

```
procedure TMyCustomThread.Execute;
begin
  while not self.Terminated do begin
    try
      FGoEvent.WaitFor(INFINITE);
      FGoEvent.ResetEvent;
      if self.Terminated then break;
      MainExecute;        
    except
      HandleException;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Here `FGoEvent` is a `TEvent`. The implementing class defines what the work package looks like in the abstract `MainExecute` method, but whatever it is the thread will perform its work and then return to waiting for the `FGoEvent` to signal that it has new work to do.

In your case, you need to keep track of which threads are waiting and which are working. You will probably want a manager class of some sort to keep track of these thread objects.  Assigning something simple like a threadID to each one seems sensible.  For each thread, just before launching it, make a record that it is currently busy.  At the very end of your work package you can then post a message back to the manager class telling it that the work is done (and that it can flag the thread as available for work).

When you add work to the queue you can first check for available threads to run the work (or create a new one if you wish to follow the model you outlined).  If there are threads then launch the task, if there are not then push the work onto the work queue.  When worker threads report complete the manager can check the queue for outstanding work.  If there is work it can immediately re-deploy the thread.  If there isn't work it can flag the thread as available for work (here you might use a second queue for available workers).

A full implementation is too complex to document in a single answer here - this aims just to rough out some general ideas.

Comment: Thanks @J... this is a really good direction. I will try this :)

Comment: Rather than give each thread its own event, I would have an event on the queue instead. Lock the queue, add an item, signal the event, and unlock the queue. Any idle thread can wait on that event. When signaled, the idle threads can then lock the queue, pull out an item if available, reset the event if the queue is empty, and unlock the queue. If that is not efficient enough, use an I/O Completion Port instead. Have idle threads wait on the IOCP, then simply post work items to the IOCP and let the OS tell each idle thread which specific item to work on. No locking or events needed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau All good stuff, agreed - this answer was only simple example of *one* way to do this (to illustrate the concept).

Comment: @J... So, how do you check if there is a thread that is not busy?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  I think I suggested clearly enough that one needs to keep track of which threads are working and which are waiting.  The answer was deliberately written at a higher level to address the question.  There are implementation details that could be expounded upon at each point along the way.  I can make this a much longer answer.  Do you see value in that?